# Extract image from wpf image control and save it to a png file on my local PCc#

Tags: wpf

i have a image control in wpf c#.

```
<Image x:Name="icon01" MouseDown="icon_MouseDown" Cursor="Hand" Source="FavIcon\01.png" Height="48" Width="48" Margin="10"/>
```

How can I save the image (FavIcon\01.png) to file on my PC? i use c# .net 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `icon01.Source`(`ImageSource`) to create a `FileStream` via the `PngBitmapEncoder`, here an example using a `SaveFileDialog`

```
 private void icon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp, *.png, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg"
            };
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {

                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)icon01.Source));
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                    encoder.Save(stream);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

and the Xaml is the Same :

```
 <Grid>

    <Image x:Name="icon01" MouseDown="icon_MouseDown" Cursor="Hand" Source="FavIcon\01.png" Height="48" Width="48" Margin="10"/>

</Grid>
```